# No warnings for that function int f() doesn't return any value?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, compiler-construction

```
struct A
{
    int f()
    {} // Notice here! 
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a = a;
}
```

My compiler is the latest VC++ compiler (Visual Studio 2013 Preview)

The function A::f doesn't return any value; but no compiler warnings or errors! Why?

Comment: It's not legal, it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you try to call function f in VS2013, then the error will occur.

Comment: Did you enable all warnings? On GCC this warning is not enabled by default.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx

Comment: @NeilKirk That's nonsense. The OP is expecting a compile-time warning; compile-time warnings cannot occur at execution time.

Comment: You can turn up the warning level of your compiler and it will warn you. Also if you tell the compiler to treat warnings as errors (as most warnings are logical errors in your code) then it will refuse to compile code like this without you explicitly telling it to ignore the warning.

Comment: @JimBalter If you don't call the function anywhere in your code, VS2013 doesn't generate an error.

Comment: @NeilKilk Still nonsense ... the warning is *compile-time*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ compiler isn't required to issue a diagnostic on not returning a value but if your program ever exits a non-`void` function (other than `main()`) without a return statement by falling off its end, the behavior is undefined. That is, it is legal for the compiler to compile the code but it won't be legal to ever call this function `f()` as it will result in undefined behavior.

The main reason for not requiring the compiler to issue a diagnostic, i.e., to make the behavior undefined, is that it sometimes impossible to tell whether a function will, indeed, return from a function. For example, imagine a function like that:

```
int f() {
    if(somecondition) { return 0; }
    this_function_throws();
}
```

where `this_function_throws()` is in a separate translation unit and always ends up throwing an exception.

Comment: § 6.6.3/2 is the relevant standardese.

Comment: I thought it was a typo, but it also made sense with *exists*, in an ungrammatic sort of way... The part about falling off the end is pretty important though, since exit via exception is well-defined.

Comment: Odd that this was accepted, as it doesn't answer the question, which was why VS didn't issue a warning, not whether the standard requires a warning. The reason the compiler didn't issue a warning is almost certainly because the OP didn't specify an appropriate warning level.

Comment: Last I checked, for coherence with C, calling f is still legal but you must ignore the return value.

Comment: @Joshua: Yu Hao's answer makes it plainly clear that falling off the end is UB, and therefore it is UB to call `f`.

Comment: VC++ implements an older version of the standard where it wasn't undefined to fall off the end of an int function only if the value was ignored.

Comment: @Joshua: Falling off the end of a non-`void` function was always undefined behavior in C++. Pretty much the same clause as 6.6.3 appeared in the previous version of the C++ standard, e.g., in the same clause of C++03: "... Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined
behavior in a value-returning function." Seems the words didn't even change!

Comment: This compiler is also a C compiler. Before you ask why this compiler considers it undefined or not you have to check not only every C++ standard going all the way back, but every C standard going all the way back to pcc. It turns out there is a very old standard in C that this behavior is defined, and this compiler implements the definition.

Answer (score 6):

It's undefined behavior, but the compiler isn't required to report this.

> **C++11(ISO/IEC 14882:2011) §6.6.3 *The return statement***
>
> A return statement without an expression can be used only in functions that do not return a value, that is, a function with the return type void, a constructor (12.1), or a destructor (12.4). A return statement with an expression of non-void type can be used only in functions returning a value; the value of the expression is returned to the caller of the function. The
> expression is implicitly converted to the return type of the function in which it appears. A return statement can involve the construction and copy of a temporary object (12.2). **Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.**